# Defining common error messages with preprocessor C++

Tags: c++, error-handling, c-preprocessor

Let's say I have multiple places where I call function `int foo(x, y)`. Based on the return code, I decide whether to print an error message or not. So the code looks similar to this:

```
  void func1()
    {
        ...
        if(foo(x,y))
            std::cerr << "Error occurred with values" << x << "," << y << __LINE__;
        ...
    }

    void func2()
    {
        ...
        if(foo(x,y))
            std::cerr << "Error occurred with values" << x << "," << y << __LINE__;
        ...
    }
```

The problem that I have is that `"Error occurred"` is repeating in many places and is the same everywhere. I was wondering if it's a good practice to define common error messages using `#define` and reuse them. So the code would like like this:

```
  #define errMsg(x,y) \
    std::string("Error occurred with values " + to_string(x) + "," + to_string(y) + to_string(__LINE__))

  void func1()
    {
        ...
        if(foo(x,y))
            std::cerr << errMsg;
        ...
    }

    void func2()
    {
        ...
        if(foo(x,y))
            std::cerr << errMsg;
        ...
    }
```

Comment: I hope it wouldn't look just that like that, because that won't compile...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious thing to do is just to put the error message in `foo` itself.  If you can't do that, then just wrap it:

```
bool fooWithLogging(int x, iny y)
{
    auto result = foo(x,y);
    if (result)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error occurred with values" << x << "," << y << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The call the wrapper in your code:

```
void func1()
{
    ...
    fooWithLogging(x,y);
    ...
}

void func2()
{
    ...
    fooWithLogging(x,y);
    ...
}
```

Bonus: make the logging dynamic:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
bool g_isFooLoggingEnabled = true;
#else
bool g_isFooLoggingEnabled = false;
#endif

bool fooWithLogging(int x, iny y)
{
    auto result = foo(x,y);
    if (result && g_isFooLoggingEnabled)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error occurred with values" << x << "," << y << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And now with your FILE and LINE requirement that just alluded to in the comments:

```
bool _fooWithLogging(int x, iny y, const std::string& filename, int line)
{
    auto result = foo(x,y);
    if (result && g_isFooLoggingEnabled)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error occurred in file" << filename << " on line " << line << " with values" << x << "," << y << std::endl;
    }
}

#define FooWithLogging(x, y) _fooWithLogging(x, y, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

Then in code:

```
void func1()
{
    ...
    FooWithLogging(x,y);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can't add message to foo. What if I also want to print the file and line where the error occurred with `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`? Using a wrapper will not let me to do that

Comment: @ReeSSult - answer updated to reflect your new requirements.